# Can a program written in C get/print the time of compilation?

Tags: c, gcc

So what I want is to have some preprocessor which gives the time of compilation. So that I can know which version of the program I'm running, by printing that time. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to know which version you are running from within the application at run time?

Comment: Use a version control system (like hg http://mercurial.selenic.com/ or SVN http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Comment: @EdHeal: I'm already using SVN, but there is a separate server where I compile and run the application. The server where I run the program is supposed to be synchronized with the one where I compile, but sometimes it fails to synchronize. That is why I'm interested in knowing the compilation time, so that I know which version is running, that is, whether synchronization actually happened or not. And by the way, the server where I run doesn't even have SVN with which I can check the version, only the compilation server has it.

Comment: @MetallicPriest - See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("%s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
  return 0;
}
```

Other [standard predefined macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` macros, as described [in the official documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: That is beautiful .. i din't know about this at all . You learn everyday on this site. Thank you

Comment: @sukhvir You're welcome. As you might have perceived, there already is a question about this. Next time make sure to use the site search before posting a question.

Comment: Dude i didn't post this question ..

Comment: @sukhvir Ah OK, alright. Typically it's the OP that says "thanks" and I didn't read your username carefully... I retract, sorry.